# REGGEX Matching just once inside multiple delimiters

Tags: regex

In a pattern X-Y-Z where the delimiters are "-" i want to check if Y has the size 8 without repetions.

Y could be a subset like Y = (A-B-C) but Y just has a value 1 if there's no

1 - num-12345678-num -> In this case I want that Y has a value.
2 - num-12345678-234-213-num -> Since Y is a subset (12345678-234-213) Y should have a different value.

The reggex i'm using is '-([0-9]*)-' and works for the 1st case however gets the same value for the second. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding a hyphen to the character class - [`'-([0-9-]*)-'`](https://regex101.com/r/7JZZvt/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot ;) It worked!

Comment: I tested and all when well although theres a particular case where it fails.

X-8551-03-24-13.20.29.709622-Z

In this case and because of  the point at this position "13.20" it fails.

If i change the "." to a "-" it works but if i just deleted having "..1320.." it also fails.

Any change of knowing whats happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You either need to add the `.` to the character class - [`-([0-9.-]*)-`](https://regex101.com/r/hdtiSx/1) or just match anything between the first and last `-`: [`-(.*)-`](https://regex101.com/r/hdtiSx/2).

Comment: Again you were right ;) Thanks again! :D

Comment: If you provided exact requirements, it would be easier to provide a definitive, final answer.

Comment: Yes i know, but working with volatile requirements doesn't allow me to have certainties :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a hyphen to the character class:

```
-([0-9-]*)-
      ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JZZvt/1)

If you put it at the end of the char class, you do not need to escape it.

**Details**:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `([0-9-]*)` - Group 1 capturing zero or more (due to the `*` quantifier) digits or/and hyphens
- `-` - a literal hyphen again.

Comment: Got it ;) Thanks a lot for the feedback ;)

Comment: I was trying to vote up but wasn't enabled! Then checked the inbox and see that was available because of the points ;) done and thanks again!